# Solving a congruence over a cubic field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a cubic field, and let $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$ where $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$. For $x \in K$ let $x^\prime$ and $x^{\prime \prime}$ denote respectively the two Galois conjugates of $x$. Note that for $x,y \in K$ we have that

$$\displaystyle x^{\prime \prime} y y^\prime + x^\prime y y^{\prime \prime} \in K.$$

This is because $y^\prime y^{\prime \prime} \in K$, and $\text{Tr}(x y^\prime y^{\prime \prime}) \in \mathbb{Q} \subset K$. Hence

$$\displaystyle x^{\prime \prime} y y^\prime + x^\prime y y^{\prime \prime} = \text{Tr}(x y^\prime y^{\prime \prime}) - x y^\prime y^{\prime \prime} \in K,$$

as claimed.

My question is: for fixed $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ which is not divisible by a rational integer other than $\pm 1$, how to find the set of $\beta \in \mathcal{O}_K$ satisfying

$$\displaystyle \alpha^\prime \alpha^{\prime \prime} \text{ divides } \alpha^{\prime \prime} \beta \beta^\prime + \alpha^\prime \beta \beta^{\prime \prime} - \alpha \beta^\prime \beta^{\prime \prime}?$$

Comment: Divides in *which ring*?

Comment: @KCd both things are elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$, so I am asking for divisibility there